# pyspark spark.read input file datetime , like using input_file_name()

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read some jsons from An azure blob storage as a dataframe

there is a function to input the filename like using a builtin function input_file_name() during spark.read.

are there any similar buildin function for reading the file timestamp ?

if no?

how we can read the timestamp of the input file along with the data ?

is anyone has any idea to do that? any workaround ?

Comment: You can use the `to_date` function for that. If you add an example of your input data (as an edit to your question), we'll be able to give you an example in code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the file's modification date? If so, you can use the metadata column *file_modification_time*.
This can be done as follows:

```
df = (spark.read.format('json').load(filepath)
      .select('*', '_metadata.file_modification_time')
      )
```

Documentation:
https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/file-metadata-column.html#supported-metadata

Comment: very nice , but I am using databricks spark 9.x

Comment: @mytabi Databricks Runtime 9.x? Is there a specific reason for this? In most cases it is recommended to use the latest runtime

Comment: does this work with spark sql? (like input_file_name() ). In our framework, I don't have access to custom select in python/scala, just spark sql. I still can use custom options (like delimiter, encoding, etc)

Comment: Yes it does. Here is even an example in SQL
https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/file-metadata-column.html#use-in-copy-into